# How to implement Tasks in function? c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, task-parallel-library

I have to multiply matrix by vector using class Task from TPL (it's labaratory work and I have to). I did it using Parallel For and it works but now I'm stuck because I have no idea how to implement it using tasks.

```
public static int[] matxvecParallel(int [,] mat, int[] vec)ParallelFor
    {            
        int[] res = new int[mat.GetLength(0)];
        Parallel.For(0, mat.GetLength(0), i =>
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < mat.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                res[i] += mat[i, k] * vec[k];
            }

        });
        return res;
    }
```

I did something stupid to find out how tasks works and I still don't understand.
How to change my code?

```
public static int[] matxvecTask(int[,] mat, int[] vec) 
    {
        int[] res = new int[mat.GetLength(0)];
        int countTasks = 4;
        Task[] arrayOfTasks = new Task[countTasks];

        for (int k = 0; k < mat.GetLength(0); k++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < countTasks; i++)
            {
            int index = i;
            arrayOfTasks[index] = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        res[i] += mat[i, j] * vec[j];
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything asynchronous so there's no need to use Tasks; it would just add overhead.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with tasks? This really is something that is clear cut for parallel programming. `Task` represents some work. That work can be done or ongoing. You can wait for that work to finish and once it's done and it has a result you can use that result. Tasks might be excecuted in parallel, they might not be. For a case like this where you just want to do some cpu bound work in parallel, tasks won't gain you anything

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, change this line to use `index` instead of `i`:

```
res[index] += mat[index, j] * vec[j];
```

When you use `i`, you fall in the [trap of closures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271447/383426).

Then, you should also wait for all the tasks to complete before moving on to the next iteration:

```
Task.WaitAll(arrayOfTasks);
```

Now, you will gain absolutely nothing if you replace `Parallel.For` with tasks.  You only make your code more complicated.  Both tasks and `Parallel` will execute your computations on the thread pool.  However, `Parallel` is optimized especially for the purpose and it easier to write and read.